# What is karma, Is it physical?

Tags: karma

**See I am not asking about the law of karma. But karma it self**.

There is an Indian philosophy that think the karma is atoms(or like it) .

So what about Hinduism. Do *karma* physically exist. Is karma attached to soul?

If karma is attached to soul what makes it attached to soul?

---

<sup>What is karma? To make it easy to understand.
Let me give an example. If I ask what is gravity, one can say it is a force of nature. That's what I mean by my question</sup>

Comment: karma is stored in bhagavan's manas, like a bank account for each atma. punya = santosha in bhagavan's hruday, paap = krodha in bhagavan's hruday.

Comment: Karmas are stored in encrypted form in one's horoscope and are released in the format of dasha system, most feared and release being sade sati. Thats why hindus have been doing horoscope matching for ages prior to marriage. If some person's nature is of anger, his horoscope will show manglik dosha and should be married to another manglik. But who made him manglik at birth? His previous birth accumulated Karmas.“A child is born on that day and at that hour when the celestial rays are in mathematical harmony with his individual karma.”— Yukteswar Giri

Comment: this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda who's duplicate.